# Convergent Finite Difference Method for Variable Coefficient Hyperbolic Equation

Tags: numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the hyperbolic equation $u_t+sin(x)u_x-yu_y=0$ on the domain $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\times[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ with some initial condition $u(x,y,0)=\phi(x,y)$. Set up a convergent finite difference method and justify it.

My thought is to use a straightforward scheme that is backward time, central space. However, since this is not a linear PDE, the Lax equivalence theorem no longer applies. Is my scheme correct? If so, how could I fully justify it?

Comment: It is a linear PDE, just not with constant coefficients. A time bound like $2\,dt\le min(dx, dy/max(|y|))$ still applies, in first place to avoid that the system matrix gets close to singular, you could check with some small grids how the condition number behaves.